# ng build failed: sass error: null is not a color

Tags: angular, sass, ng-build

Im working a project which now updates to angular 15 and while trying to setup a test environment, build/start throw this error for what seems to be related to material and themes and sass.
it also seems to be related to progress bar.
this is what i get:
`

```
./src/theme/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ../../node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ../../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: $color: null is not a color.
   ╷
16 │     track-color: color.adjust(mdc-theme-color.prop-value($color), $alpha: -0.75),
   │                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/progress-bar/_progress-bar-theme.scss 16:18  -palette-styles()
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/progress-bar/_progress-bar-theme.scss 28:7   @content
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/core/mdc-helpers/_mdc-helpers.scss 176:5     @content
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/core/mdc-helpers/_mdc-helpers.scss 216:3     disable-mdc-fallback-declarations()
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/core/mdc-helpers/_mdc-helpers.scss 175:3     using-mdc-theme()
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/progress-bar/_progress-bar-theme.scss 26:3   color()
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/progress-bar/_progress-bar-theme.scss 53:7   @content
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_theming.scss 402:3             private-check-duplicate-theme-styles()
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/progress-bar/_progress-bar-theme.scss 47:3   theme()
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_all-theme.scss 47:5            @content
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_theming.scss 402:3             private-check-duplicate-theme-styles()
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/_all-theme.scss 44:3            all-component-themes()
  ../../node_modules/@angular/material/core/color/_all-color.scss 15:3              all-component-colors()
  src/theme/styles.scss 49:3                                                        root stylesheet
```

`

how do i begin with this? sorry for the low description if someone guide me for further details if would be great.

I tried to update to angular 15 and start a local testing environment with `ng build` or `ng start` but it stuck on this.

i have this at styles.scss:

```
@include mat.all-component-colors($myapp-theme); // Progress bars don't work without this
```

and this in the variables.scss file:

```
$myapp-theme: mat.define-light-theme($app-primary, $app-accent, $app-warn);
```

which is supposed to be related.

any guidence will be much appriciated.

*using node 16 npm 8 and angular 15.

Comment: delete the node_module folder and do the npm install again, make sure you are using the right node version.

Comment: I've tried it again now but this continues. the node and npm versions are as they should be by the app requirements. and I get no error regarding the node.

Comment: I think I need to import or change the current import of the angular/material thing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is with a slightly changed syntax of angular 15. first, I needed to `import '@angular/material' as mat`, and then I needed to adjust a new `mat` properties to use the `mdc` syntax for example for button/color.

I used the angular documentation for this fix.
good luck to future stuckers.

Comment: In my case I had several `@include mat.all-component-themes` I had to remove it and just apply the theme where I needed, in my case the progress-bar-color `@include mat.progress-bar-color`. Done checking the new theming docs https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was a slight change in the accepted syntax in theming over angular material 15 migration.

in angular material **14**, this syntax is accepted :

```
$my-primary: mat.$indigo-palette;
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);

$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $my-primary,
   accent: $my-accent,
 )
));
```

However in angular material **15** all palettes used to create a theme must be defined as a palette with mat.define-palette  :

```
$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
```

Comment: This was the issue for me. I was defining a custom palette to a variable but I then needed to use $mat-myapp-primary: mat.define-palette($mat-myapp-custom);